# Problems on WSO2 with Oracle RDS Amazon integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

When I accessed this URL http://my.domain.com:9763/services/Test_DataService.SOAP12Endpoint, I received the message bellow:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
    <soapenv:Reason xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">
        The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is          /services/User_DataService.SOAP12Endpoint and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was    previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.
        </soapenv:Text>
    </soapenv:Reason>
```

I tested the WSO2 DSS 2.7 and 3 local and remote with Oracle RDS on Amazon (the same error on all cases).

What's happening?

Comment: How can I change the EPR?? "The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are accessing the service in a wrong way.

As you might know, [WSO2 Data Services Server](http://wso2.com/products/data-services-server/) uses [Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) services to [expose your data service as a web service](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Architecture).

So, you should know how to invoke Web (Axis2) services from a client.

When you successfully create a data service, you should be able to see the relevant service in the services list. Then you can use the "[Service Dashboard](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Service+Dashboard)" to view the service's WSDL and manage QoS

Following error from Axis2 [usually indicate that you are not invoking the web service properly](http://www.keith-chapman.org/2009/02/axis2-endpoint-reference-epr-for.html).

> The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is          /services/User_DataService.SOAP12Endpoint and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was    previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.

You should be able to test the service from in-built [Try It](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Testing+WSDLs) feature from Service Dashboard. [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) is also a great tool to test Web Services. You can just point the [WSDL in soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/working-with-wsdls.html) and create a project. You can then manually invoke listed service operations under the soapUI project.

I hope this helps!

Comment: WSDLException (at /soapenv:Reason): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Expected element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions'.

Comment: Thanks Isuru,

I have been test the data service like I did a lot of times, with Try resource.

The WSO2 DSS data source with Oracle DB have a Health Connection, but the Try doesn't run.

I installed soapUI, but the project doesn't run correctly on it. I received this message:

WSDLException (at /soapenv:Reason): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Expected element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions'.

The wsdl url that I used was this: my.domain:9763/services/Teste?wsdl

Comment: Can you access the WSDL from your browser? If so, you can download it and use it for the soapUI project.

Comment: Thank you Isuru, I'm testing soapUI.