# How can I set the endpoint reference (EPR) on WSO2 DSS

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

On this URL: http://my.domain.com:9763/services/Test_DataService.SOAP12Endpoint, I received the message bellow:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
    <soapenv:Reason xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">
        The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is          /services/User_DataService.SOAP12Endpoint and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was    previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.
        </soapenv:Text>
    </soapenv:Reason>
```

PS: I tested the WSO2 DSS 2.7 and 3 local and remote with Oracle RDS on Amazon (the same error on all cases).

Someone can help-me please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems on WSO2 with Oracle RDS Amazon integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680597/problems-on-wso2-with-oracle-rds-amazon-integration)

Comment: Hi, please don't repost your question. The WSO2 people try to keep up but there's no guarantees. Can you edit your previous question with the call you're making in order to get this response?

Comment: I answered a similar question [here][1].

Thanks!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18690466/1955702

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18690466/1955702).

Please make sure you are invoking service property. Please note that you just cannot access the EPR from your browser. You should use a web service (SOAP) client.

In-build Try It feature and soapUI tool are good options for testing.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Isuru, I tested with the same steps that other times. The difference is that I use Amazon now. But I have access on Amazon Oracle DB.

Comment: Regardless of the data source, the data service is accessed in similar way. Were you able to test the data service with a local database? Perhaps you could try Oracle XE (Express Edition)